# Pro's Con's getting groovy script from filesystem vs database

Tags: groovy

what are the pro's and con's of using GroovyClassLoader, getting groovy scripts from the Filesystem vs Database, in term of performance, what kind of precaution need to be taken

Comment: It depends. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i want see the performance on both approaches,where i can maintain n number of scripts with the latest compile cache, where the script can be  added/deleted or replaced frequently

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer cannot really be answered easily. You have the cost of the lookup and the actual loading of the source that is different, but that is not Groovy being responsible here, it is in one case the disc, in the other case the database. I can only say: test it with production constraints.